# How to properly implement both __str__ and __repr__

Tags: python

In several of my classes, I want to implement both `__str__` and `__repr__` and usually end up with code like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __str__(self):
        return 'MyClass({})'.format(self.a)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'MyClass({!r})'.format(self.a)
```

Which does what I'd expect:

```
>>> myobject = MyClass(np.array([1, 2]))
>>> str(myobject)
'MyClass([1 2])'
>>> repr(myobject)
'MyClass(array([1, 2]))'
```

However the code violates DRY and as the number of arguments starts to grow maintaining this becomes cumbersome and I've often found that either of `__str__` or `__repr__` has come "out of sync" with the other.

Is there a better way to simultaneously implement both `__str__` and `__repr__` without duplication?

Comment: Is it really necessary for `str` and `repr` to return two different strings?

Comment: You could just say `__str__ = __repr__` (or vice versa) to copy the implementation.

Comment: It is not necessary that they return different string, but often preferable. Perhaps this example is to simple to convey that.

Comment: You probably want to look into [attrs](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs).

Answer (score 5):

Since your `__str__` and `__repr__` follow the same pattern, you could write a function to create the object's string representation for you. It would take an object, a list of attributes and `str` or `repr` as arguments:

```
def stringify(obj, attrs, strfunc):
    values = []
    # get each attribute's value and convert it to a string
    for attr in attrs:
        value = getattr(obj, attr)
        values.append(strfunc(value))

    # get the class name
    clsname = type(obj).__name__

    # put everything together
    args = ', '.join(values)
    return '{}({})'.format(clsname, args)

print( stringify(MyClass('foo'), ['a'], repr) )
# output: MyClass('foo')
```

---

I would recommend putting this function in a class which you then inherit from:

```
class Printable:
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__stringify(str)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__stringify(repr)

    def __stringify(self, strfunc):
        values = []
        for attr in self._attributes:
            value = getattr(self, attr)
            values.append(strfunc(value))

        clsname = type(self).__name__
        args = ', '.join(values)
        return '{}({})'.format(clsname, args)

class MyClass(Printable):
    _attributes = ['a']

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
```

And you can even get it done completely automatically by grabbing the attributes directly from the `__init__` function's signature:

```
import inspect

class AutoPrintable:
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__stringify(str)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__stringify(repr)

    def __stringify(self, strfunc):
        sig= inspect.signature(self.__init__)
        values= []
        for attr in sig.parameters:
            value= getattr(self, attr)
            values.append(strfunc(value))

        clsname= type(self).__name__
        args= ', '.join(values)
        return '{}({})'.format(clsname, args)

class MyClass(AutoPrintable):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

print( str(MyClass('foo', 'bar')) ) # output: MyClass(foo, bar)
print( repr(MyClass('foo', 'bar')) ) # output: MyClass('foo', 'bar')
```

Answer (score 4):

Neither the official Python documentation nor the [Index of Python Enhancement Proposal](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/) seem to specify clear guidelines on how to override these methods, except for the [3.3 Special method names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) which, among other things, says of `__repr__()`:

> If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression
>   that could be used to recreate an object with the same value [...]
>   This is typically used for debugging, so it is important that the
>   representation is information-rich and  unambiguous.

I like to take inspiration from how `__repr__()` is implemented in some of the standard library modules, take e.g. `socket.socket`:

```
$ python3
>>> from socket import socket
>>> socket()
<socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 0)>
```

So the pattern here is `<self.__class__.__module__ + "." + self.__class__.__name__ attribute1=value1, ..., attributeN=valueN>`.

While `__repr__()` is preferred for debug/testing purposes, the scope of `__str__()` is much more informal and I'd deduce that even looser rules apply. Note that if `__repr__()` is overridden but `__str__()` is not, `__repr__()` calls `__str__()`.

Here again, if I have to pick some rules I prefer to have `__str__()` resemble `__repr__()`, but modifying:

- The number of items displayed. I don't need to be verbose as `__repr__` mandates.
- The type of values displayed. I include the most "important" ones, and even values that do not reflect the arguments initially passed to `__init__()`.

Another few examples come from a PDF library I've been working on. There are two `PdfFileReader` and `PdfFileWriter` classes, and their `__repr__()` and `__str__()` methods have the following output:

```
r = PdfFileReader("samplecode/pdfsamples/jpeg.pdf")
w = PdfFileWriter()

print(r)
print(str(r))
print(repr(r))

print(w)
print(str(w))
print(repr(w))
```

---

```
$ python3 repr.py
<pypdf.pdf.PdfFileReader _filepath=samplecode/pdfsamples/jpeg.pdf, stream=<_io.BytesIO object at 0x7eff60f07e60>, strict=True, debug=False>
<pypdf.pdf.PdfFileReader _filepath=samplecode/pdfsamples/jpeg.pdf, stream=<_io.BytesIO object at 0x7eff60f07e60>, strict=True, debug=False>
<pypdf.pdf.PdfFileReader _filepath=samplecode/pdfsamples/jpeg.pdf, stream=<_io.BytesIO object at 0x7eff60f07e60>, strict=True, debug=False>
<pypdf.pdf.PdfFileWriter _header=%PDF-1.3, debug=False>
<pypdf.pdf.PdfFileWriter _header=%PDF-1.3, debug=False>
<pypdf.pdf.PdfFileWriter _header=%PDF-1.3, debug=False>
```

See also [2. Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) for `repr()`:

> [...] For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that
>   would yield an object **with the same value when passed to eval()**,
>   otherwise the representation is a string enclosed in angle brackets
>   that contains the name of the type of the object together with
>   additional information often including the name and address of the
>   object. [...]

Answer (score 3):

There are no rules nor clear guidelines for implementing `__str__` and `__repr__`—at least none that are consistently followed anywhere (not even in the stdlib). So there wouldn’t be a way to get the “standard behavior” automatically, simply because there isn’t a standard behavior. It’s up to you, so if you set up guidelines for yourself, maybe you can also come up with a utility to make it easier for you to follow them.

In your case, you could for example create a base class which provides the `__str__` and `__repr__` implementations:

```
class AutoStRepr(object):
    _args = []
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({})'.format(type(self).__name__,
            ', '.join(repr(getattr(self, a)) for a in self._args))
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}({})'.format(type(self).__name__,
            ', '.join(str(getattr(self, a)) for a in self._args))
```

You could then use that on a number of different types:

```
class MyClass(AutoStRepr):
    _args = ['a']
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class MyOtherClass(AutoStRepr):
    _args = ['a', 'bc']
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.bc = b * c
```

```
>>> MyClass('foo')
MyClass('foo')
>>> MyOtherClass('foo', 2, 5)
MyOtherClass('foo', 10)
```

Comment: Not a bad answer, but in a way this violates the DRY principle just as much as the original solution - you'd probably want to move those two massive `.format`s into a helper function.

Comment: @Rawing Those “massive joins”? How are they massive? It’s just a join over a simple generator expression. And no, that’s not a violation of DRY; any solution to avoid repeating that would just add a crazy amount of complexity that has no actual benefit. DRY is about avoid having the same logic over and over. This here is *two times* and it’s actually a different logic which might end up diverging even more.

Answer (score 2):

No need for duplication, just don't implement `__str__`.

That way, the object will behave like `__str__ = __repr__`.

I think you should also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python).

Comment: I am well aware of the possibility to not duplicate, but for "large" objects, the difference, here just `array(...)`, can be quite large and having both str and repr can be useful.

Comment: Then follow the `__repr__` is unambiguous `__str__` is readable guideline. The implementation is totaly up to your definition of unambiguous and readable.

Comment: I think this is an bad idea, because: `__str__` has the purpose to return an **usable and readable representation** by `str()`. But `__repr__` has the purpose to return an string for **reproducing** the instance by `eval(repr())`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Quaternion:
    _x: float = 0.0
    _y: float = 0.0
    _z: float = 0.0
    _w: float = 1.0

    @property
    def x(self) -> float:
        return self._x

    @property
    def y(self) -> float:
        return self._y

    @property
    def z(self) -> float:
        return self._z

    @property
    def w(self) -> float:
        return self._w

    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float, z: float, w: float) -> None:
        self._x = float(x)
        self._y = float(y)
        self._z = float(z)
        self._w = float(w)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return ", ".join(
            (
                str(self._x),
                str(self._y),
                str(self._z),
                str(self._w)
            )
        )

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        cls = self.__class__
        module = cls.__module__
        return f"{module + '.' if module != '__main__' else ''}{cls.__qualname__}({str(self)})"
```

### Pros

- `str()` returns the pure values: `0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0`
- `repr()` returns something like: `Quaternion(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` or `mymodule.Quaternion(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` *(if it's in an imported submodule)*. So you are able to reproduce it easily by `eval(repr())`

### Cons

Don't know any, yet.